# Balanced parenthesis, how to count them?

Tags: java, string

I need to write a java program that tells you if the parenthesis are balanced in a string, I can't find the correct way to do it though.
I already know I am going to use a loop to count the open and closed parenthesis `"(" = 1 and ")" = -1` stored in an integer that would come back as `0` or anything else.

I just don't know how to count the parenthesis that way.

Edit: To be clearer, all i really need is a way to count the parentheses and i am blocked because i can't work with something like :

if (args[i] == '(')   //the interpreter will not let me compare strings with chars
    count++;

Edit 2 :

```
public class Testing_grounds {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = args[];
        char RetV[] = str.toCharArray();
        int counter = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n <= RetV.length; n++) {
            if (RetV[n] == '(')
                counter++;
            else if (RetV[n] == ')')
                counter--;
        }
        if (counter == 0)
            System.out.println("The parentheses are balenced!");
        else if(counter < 0)
            System.out.println("There are to many closed parenthesis!");
        else if(counter > 0)
            System.out.println("There are to many opened parenthesis!");
    }
}
```

This is pretty much the code i'm going for (i'm trying to get the toCharArray() method to work but i keep getting class expected error on the 3rd line. That line is there because it won't let me do : args.toCharArray)

Remember that i need to do this with an input and not a string already present in the code.

Comment: Can you paste the program

Comment: I think in addition you have to consider the order they appear; `))((` is wrong and `()()` is Ok and both cases will return `0`

Comment: Don't forget to skip over parentheses in quoted strings. That makes this problem difficult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you scan the string character by character, then you can do something like this:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i=0; i<text_length; i++) {
    if (text[i] == '(') counter++;
    else if (text[i] == ')') counter--;

    if (counter < 0) break;
}

if (counter != 0) error();
```

This code takes into account the order of the parenthesis, so ")(" will be detected as an error.

**EDIT**:

To do the same in Java you can do:

```
int counter = 0;
for (char ch : text.toCharArray())
    if (ch == '(') counter++;
    else if (ch == ')') counter--;

    if (counter < 0) break;
}
if (counter != 0) error();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is how i'm doing it but i don't know how to scan the string character by character.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post to explain how to do it in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it in several ways:

1) use a stack. Push a value every time you see a `(` and pop a value every time you see a `)`. If there's nothing to pop (stack exception) then it's not balanced. This approach is nice because if you use a stack of `char` you can easily extend it to handle other types of parenthesis by having a simple mapping of closing parenthesis to opening parenthesis (i.e. `] -> [, ) -> (, } -> {`) and checking if what you popped is ok for what you encountered in the string.

Something like this:

```
Stack<Character> openParens = new Stack<>();
for(Character ch: text.toCharArray()) {
    if(ch == '(') {
        openParens.push(ch);
    } else if(ch == ')') {
        if(openParens.empty()) {
            return false; //unbalanced
        } else {
            openParens.pop();
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

This will not work if parenthesis order is not important, though.

2) use a counter, add `1` when you notice a `(` and remove `1` when you see a `)`. If you go below 0 return false (unbalanced). Or go until the end of the string and then check if the count is `0`, this will handle cases when you don't require ordering (just when the count of `(` == `)`)

@EDIT:

Ok so the problem is `String str = args[];` won't compile if you don't provide the index (i.e. `String str = args[0];`). Also you cannot call `toCharArray()` on `args` because that's a method defined on the `String` class and `args` is an **array** of `String`s.

I would not recommend passing the text you want to count that way, it's not easy to use afterwards. How about instead you ass a test file name containing your text and read that instead?

Comment: The second method is what i tried to do but i keep encountering the same probleme : Error:(11, 24) java: incomparable types: java.lang.String and char

Comment: @ThierryL could you please add your code to the question? Are you trying to compare like this `ch == ")"` where `ch` is a `char`? This won't work -> you need to use `'`.

Comment: I put in the code i have at the moment, and i tried doing char== '(' but the problem is i would get the can't compare char and string so now i'm trying to use a toCharArray() method but i still get problems

Answer (score 1):

Read the string from start to finish, use a stack to count the parentheses. Push only the opening parentheses into the stack, pop one if you encounter a closing parenthesis.

So something like ((a+x)*(b+y)) would leave an empty stack at the end, which tells you the parentheses are balanced.

Do you also need to consider the order eg:(a+b)))((?

Comment: That seems to be a good idea but I have zet to learn how to use stacks
And no, i onlz need to count them so things like ()( will simply output a predefined message saying there are to many opened parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you want to count the number of balanced parenthesis in a string, following java code might help

```
 int open=0,close=0;
    Stack<Character> openbrace = new Stack<Character>();

    for( char c : sample.toCharArray())
    {
        if(c=='(') {
            openbrace.push(c);
            open++;
            }
        else if(c==')') {
            if(openbrace.isEmpty()==false) {    openbrace.pop();}
            close++;
            }
    }

    if(open-close!=0)
        System.out.println("unbalanced ");
    else
        System.out.println("balanced");
    System.out.println(" count of balanced brace="+Math.min(open, close));
```

Answer (score 0):

Function calculates the unbalanced brackets.

```
public static int bracketMatch(String bracketString) {   

    Stack<Character>opening = new Stack<Character>();
    Stack<Character>closing = new Stack<Character>();
    char [] brackets = bracketString.toCharArray();
    for (char bracket: brackets) {

        if (bracket == '(') {
            opening.push(bracket);
        } else if (bracket == ')') {
            if (opening.size() > 0) {
                opening.pop();
            }
            else {
                closing.push(bracket);
            }
        }
    }

    return  opening.size()+closing.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code which returns the matching count and -1 when unmatched.

```
public int matchedCount(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Integer> stk = new Stack<Integer>();
        System.out.println("Enter expression");
        String exp = scan.next();        
        int len = exp.length();
        System.out.println("\nMatches and Mismatches:\n");
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {    
            char ch = exp.charAt(i);
            if (ch == '(')
                stk.push(i);
            else if (ch == ')')
            {
                try
                {
                    int p = stk.pop() + 1;
                    counter++;
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return -1;
                }
            }            
        }

        while (!stk.isEmpty() )
            return -1; 
        return counter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Practice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "([{{[(())]}}";

        int OpenCurlyBracket = 0;
        int ClosedCurlyBracket = 0;
        int OpenSquareBracket = 0;
        int ClosedSquareBracket = 0;
        int OpenRoundBracket = 0;
        int ClosedRoundBracket = 0;
        int curlyBracketCount = 0;
        int roundBracketCount = 0;
        int squareBracketCount = 0;

        for (char ch: str.toCharArray()) {

            switch (ch) {
            case '{': OpenCurlyBracket ++;

            break;
            case '[': OpenSquareBracket++;

            break;
            case '(': OpenRoundBracket ++;

            break;
            case '}': ClosedCurlyBracket ++;

            break;
            case ']': ClosedSquareBracket ++;

            break;
            case ')': ClosedRoundBracket ++;

            default:
                break;
            }

        }
        if (OpenCurlyBracket == ClosedCurlyBracket) {
            int counta = (OpenCurlyBracket+ClosedCurlyBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Curly Bracket:"+counta);
            curlyBracketCount = counta/2;
        }else{
            int counta = (OpenCurlyBracket+ClosedCurlyBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Curly Bracket:"+counta);
            curlyBracketCount = counta/2;
        }
        if (OpenRoundBracket == ClosedRoundBracket) {
            int countb = (OpenRoundBracket+ClosedRoundBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Round Bracket:"+countb);
            roundBracketCount = countb/2;
        }else {

            int countb = (OpenRoundBracket+ClosedRoundBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Round Bracket:"+countb);
            roundBracketCount = countb/2;
        
        }
        
        if (OpenSquareBracket == ClosedSquareBracket) {
            int countc = (OpenSquareBracket+ClosedSquareBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Square Bracket:"+countc);
            squareBracketCount = countc/2;
        }else {

            int countc = (OpenSquareBracket+ClosedSquareBracket);
            System.out.println("Total Square Bracket:"+countc);
            squareBracketCount = countc/2;
        
        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Valid Curly Bracket:"+curlyBracketCount+"\nValid Round Bracket:" +roundBracketCount+"\nValid Square Bracket:"+squareBracketCount);      

    }
}

OUTPUT:

Total Curly Bracket:4
Total Round Bracket:5
Total Square Bracket:3

Valid Curly Bracket:2
Valid Round Bracket:2
Valid Square Bracket:1
```

Comment: You should provide an explanation for that code, code-only answers are usually not recommended (unless the code is very self-explanatory and clear).

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter string full of parenthesis : ");
        String input = sc.next();
        char s1 = '{';
        char s2 = '}';
        char s3 = '(';
        char s4 = ')';
        char s5 = '[';
        char s6 = ']';


        int c1=0;
        int c2=0;
        int c3 =0;
        int c4 = 0;
        int c5 =0;
        int c6= 0;
        for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
        {
            if(input.charAt(i) == s1) {
                c1++;
            }

            if(input.charAt(i) == s2) {
                c2++;
            }
            if(input.charAt(i) == s3) {
                c3++;
            }

            if(input.charAt(i) == s4) {
                c4++;
            }

            if(input.charAt(i) == s5) {
                c5++;
            }

            if(input.charAt(i) == s6) {
                c6++;
            }
        }
        if( c1-c2 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s1 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c1 - c2));
        }
        if( c2-c1 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s2 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c2 - c1));
        }
        if( c3-c4 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s3 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c3 - c4));
        }
        if( c4-c3 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s4 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c4 - c3));
        }
        if( c5-c6 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s5 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c5 - c6));
        }
        if( c6-c5 >= 0){
            System.out.println( s6 + " is unbalanced by :" + ( c6 - c5));
        }

//        System.out.println("The Character '"+search+"' appears "+count+" times.");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

These are great answers, but I would really like a way to count that considers single and double quotes.  Many times I have brackets or braces tucked away inside them and it throws off the count.