# Dynamic Programming approach - Interleaving Parentheses

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, dynamic-programming

Below is my code for the problem described on https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_statement&pm=14635. It keeps track of possible interleaves (as described in the problem description given) through a static variable countPossible.

```
public class InterleavingParentheses{

     public static int countPossible = 0;
     public static Set<String> dpyes = new HashSet<>(); //used for dp
     public static Set<String> dpno = new HashSet<>(); //used for dp


     public static void numInterleaves(char[] s1, char[] s2, int size1, int size2){
         char[] result = new char[size1+size2];
         numInterleavesHelper(result,s1,s2,size1,size2,0,0,0);
     }


     public static void numInterleavesHelper(char[] res, char[] s1, char[] s2, int size1, int size2, int pos, int start1, int start2){
          if (pos == size1+size2){ 
               if (dpyes.contains(new String(res))){
                countPossible+=1;
               }
               else{
                    if(dpno.contains(new String(res))){
                         countPossible+=0;
                    }
                    else if (isValid(res)){
                         dpyes.add(new String(res));
                         countPossible+=1;
                    }
                    else{
                          dpno.add(new String(res));
                    }
               }
          }                       

          if (start1 < size1){
               res[pos] = s1[start1];
          numInterleavesHelper(res,s1,s2,size1,size2,pos+1,start1+1,start2);
          }
          if (start2 < size2){
               res[pos] = s2[start2];
          numInterleavesHelper(res,s1,s2,size1,size2,pos+1,start1,start2+1);
          }
     }         

     private static boolean isValid(char[] string){

         //basically checking to see if parens are balanced

         LinkedList<Character> myStack = new LinkedList<>();
         for (int i=0; i<string.length; i++){
              if (string[i] == "(".charAt(0)){
                   myStack.push(string[i]);
              }
              else{
                   if (myStack.isEmpty()){
                        return false;
                   }
                   if (string[i] == ")".charAt(0)){
                        myStack.pop();
                   }
              }       
         }
         return myStack.isEmpty();       
     }
```

}

I use the scanner class to put in the input strings s1 = "()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()" and s2 = "()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()()" into this function and while the use of the HashSet greatly lowers the time because duplicate interleaves are accounted for, large input strings still take up a lot of time. The sizes of the input strings are supposed to be at most 2500 characters and my code is not working for strings that long. How can i modify this to make it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your dp set is only used at the end, so at best you can save an `O(n)`, but you've already done many `O(n)` operations to reach that point so the algorithm completexity is about the same. For dp to be effective, you need to be reducing `O(2^n)` operations to, say `O(n^2)`.

As one of the testcases has an answer of 487,340,184, then for your program to produce this answer, it would need that number of calls to `numInterleavesHelper` because each call can only increment `countPossible` by 1. The question asking for the answer "modulo 10^9 + 7" as well indicates that there is a large number expected as an answer.

This rules out things like creating every possible resulting string, most string manipulation, and counting 1 string at a time. Even if you optimized it, then the number of iterations alone makes it unfeasible.

Instead, think of algorithms that have about 10,000,000 iterations. Each string has a length of 2500. These constraints were chosen on purpose so that 2500 * 2500 fits within this number of iterations, suggesting a 2D dp solution.

If you create an array:

```
int ways[2501][2501] = new int[2501][2501];
```

then you want the answer to be:

```
ways[2500][2500]
```

Here `ways[x][y]` is the number of ways of creating valid strings where `x` characters have been taken from the first string, and `y` characters have been taken from the second string. Each time you add a character, you have 2 choices, taking from the first string or taking from the second. The new number of ways is the sum of the previous ones, so:

```
ways[x][y] = ways[x-1][y] + ways[x][y-1]
```

You also need to check that each string is valid. They're valid if each time you add a character, the number of opening parens minus the number of closing parens is 0 or greater, and this number is 0 at the end. The number of parens of each type in every prefix of `s1` and `s2` can be precalculated to make this a constant-time check.

Comment: Just to clarify the test case having an answer of 487340184 implies many more calls to numInterleavesHelper (only the valid combinations are counted) but that just adds more validity to your description of the problem. It's not that the code is wrong, it's just not suited to the expected input size. Thanks. I'll post my revised code at some point.

Comment: Also shouldn't it be valid only when the numopenparens-numclosedparens = 0? not >=0?

Comment: Also the number of valid combinations shouldn't be the sum should it? the description of the problem says two valid strings can be concatenated to form another valid string, but another valid string can be made if you take the valid strings in s2 and place them inside a "()" bracket contained in s1

Comment: @Fancypants753 The parens should only be equal to 0 for the complete string, but greater or equal to 0 for all intermediate strings.

Comment: The recursive structure in the problem description doesn't build the strings from left to right, which makes it harder to memoize, so don't base the structure on that. Instead, you could define the same rules as: "" has value 0, "X)" has value X-1, "X(" has value X+1, value must never be negative, values of 0 form a correct sequence.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31849977/balanced-parenthesis-how-to-count-them for how to check matching with a single integer instead of a stack.